# Why is the following job scheduling command throwing an ambiguous redirect error?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have 10 users(user0-user9). Each of them have a folder named delta. There are 10 folders(folder1-folder10) in each delta folder. There's a file.txt in each of the ten folders. Why does the following job scheduling command throw an ambiguous redirect?

How do I do this without a for loop provided I need to append different random strings to each of the files?

```
crontab -e
21 15 * * 1-6 echo $(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1) >>/home/user{0..9}/delta/folder{1..10}/file.txt
```

Comment: I would first debug this by running it as a script then turn it over to crontab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to write the same output to all of the files, then you can use `tee`:

```
tr -dc a-zA-Z0-9 </dev/urandom |
    fold -w 10 |
    head -n 1 |
    tee -a /home/user{0..9}/delta/folder{1..10}/file.txt >/dev/null
```

If your goal is to append different things, then I think a loop is unavoidable. For your cron-job case, that means you'll need to wrap your command in `bash -c '...'`.

Comment: I can't get your second part. What's the mistake in the cronjob part and why does it through ambiguous redirect error? Why do you redirect the output to /dev/null?

Comment: I tried your command and why does it not throw ambiguous redirect error now?

Comment: @BenedictFlorance: I don't know how to answer your questions. If you know what "ambiguous redirect" means, then it's too obvious to explain; and if you *don't* know what it means, then why aren't you asking *that*? (Or better yet, Googling it?)

Comment: The goal is update a different random string on each file without a for loop